# Reduce arrays in object

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Lets say I have values I have assigned in array in objects. I want to use reduce() to add them up. The workflow will work like this: x-data=" {package_type: [], online_implant_meeting: [], total() { return "do the math here" }} then inside x-text="total()"

I am using alpine.js to bind stuff. How do I do the calculation inside the function?

```
 <div class="addingPrices" x-data="{package_type: [20], online_implant_meeting: [250],  total(package_type, online_implant_meeting){ 
return package_type + online_implant_meeting;
     }} >
</div>
```

Comment: I've not worked with alpine.js before. can you access `package_type` and `online_implant_meeting` inside the function this way (let say if you were to `console.log` them)?

Comment: I can access them when I console total(item, item). The problem is I get values append to each other. 20250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to do it via the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (to merge the 2 arrays) and then sum them up with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.js"></script>
<div class="addingPrices" x-data="{
    package_type: [89],
    online_implant_meeting: ['150'],

    total(package_type, online_implant_meeting) {
       return [...package_type, ...online_implant_meeting].map(Number).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0)
    }
}">
  <span x-text.number="total(online_implant_meeting, package_type )"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: ``` <div class="addingPrices" x-data="{ online_implant_meeting: [], package_type: [], total(online_implant_meeting,package_type){ 
    
        return [...online_implant_meeting, ...package_type].reduce((acc, curr)=> acc + curr, 0);
       
     }}   " id="addingPrices">``` ```<span x-text.number="total([online_implant_meeting],[package_type] )"></span>``` . Now I get get value as 015089.00  let say the values are 89, 150

Comment: inside your `<span>`, just do `x-text.number="total(online_implant_meeting, package_type )"` (without the squared brackets) - these variables already reference array values, I added the braces in my example because I was testing it via numeric literals

Comment: It returns the same values 015089.00

Comment: you must be doing something else wrong. [check out this codepen](https://codepen.io/tibebes/pen/zYqjMdM?editors=1111)

Comment: Please, check code pen I have created https://codepen.io/apetwebc/pen/RwaMWNa

Comment: Oh, you are mixing `string`s there.. that's what causing the issue

Comment: just add `.map(Number)` to fix it..

like this: `return [...online_implant_meeting, ...package_type].map(Number).reduce((acc, curr)=> acc + curr, 0); `

Comment: I owe you. Thank you very much. I am new to declarative javascript.